# Is ng-click obtrusive

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, unobtrusive-javascript

I have a line of code in a HTML file that looks like this

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" data-ng-click="ok()">Create PDF</button>
```

My question is this.  Isn't this an example of going back to using obtrusive Javascript?

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: i dont think so, it´s the way of angular to deal with html.

Comment: If you want your app to work without JavaScript enabled then you probably shouldn't be using AngularJS

Comment: @rob +1, I don't even understand how this question came to your mind as angularJS means full JS application. Maybe you need to define what "obtrusive" really mean to you

Comment: @Bixi Stackover is for people who don't understand something to find out those things from extremely intelligent people like yourself.  If my understanding of what obtrusive is and the rationale of frameworks like angularJS are is week then I am glad to get clarification from other.

Comment: Don't know why you get all fired up, my question is not a troll... What means "unobstrusive" to you when using a full JS framework ?

Comment: @Bixi Not getting fired up mate, just saying.  I was just thinking that there may be a way for a full JS framework to be as unobtrusive as JQuery can be.  Perhaps I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is.  But I don't think it's a bad thing.

I think Angular is great because you can look at the markup and you can figure out what is going on whereas if using JQuery you have no idea what is going to happen unless you look at the JavaScript.

You can use ng-if, ng-repeat, ng-show, ng-class, etc... it's a great framework to use.

You can drop ids in elements completely and abstract away large amounts of html into directives which can be reused across your application.

It results in less html in my experience because of the directives [ng-repeat + custom directives]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, I would say it's obtrusive.  But I don't think anyone ever claimed AngularJS is unobtrusive javaScript.  Quite the opposite.  It's about creating application that do amazing things - but using JavaScript by littering the HTML with all sorts of binding references and references to functions.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Angular, and that directive is reserved, I'm not sure you have an alternate way..

There is a possibility though (untested), that something like this would work to avoid that:

```
<button id="my-btn" class="btn btn-primary">Create PDF</button>
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

### script.js (pseudo-code)

```
(function() {
  var btn = document.getElementById('my-btn');
  btn['data-ng-click'] = ok;
})();
```

Comment: I don't know why, but this makes me cringe. I guess it brings back memories of making ie6 compliant websites.